# Cordova 2.0 loadUrl does not reload

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to use phonegap/cordova (version 2.0) with Android to load an external URL. The URL I pass redirects to a second URL (like hhtp://google.com redirects to http://google.your-country-iso-code).

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl(http://mywebsite.com);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I open the app the first time, it loads the webapp without any problem. After that, opening the application again, won't load the web again. It will just hang (even after forcing the process to close and reopening the app). It works using http://google.com but not the web url I need to load.

Same thing if I call loadUrl from onRestart (coming back from another activity):

```
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    super.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
}
```

What am I missing?

I also tried this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.init();
    super.appView.clearCache(true);
    //super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", false);
    super.loadUrl(getWebAppUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your access origin value in config.xml file :

It should like below if you try to access external url

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the URL loads. It is a problem with REloading a concrete URL (it also reloads www.yahoo.com for instance)